# How to get all documents under an elasticsearch index with python client ?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I'm trying to get all index document using python client but the result show me only the first document 
This is my python code :

```
res = es.search(index="92c603b3-8173-4d7a-9aca-f8c115ff5a18", doc_type="doc", body = {
'size' : 10000,
'query': {
    'match_all' : {}
}
})
print("%d documents found" % res['hits']['total'])
data = [doc for doc in res['hits']['hits']]
for doc in data:
    print(doc)
    return "%s %s %s" % (doc['_id'], doc['_source']['0'], doc['_source']['5'])
```

Comment: seems like there is only 1 doc for `doc_type=doc`. can you recheck.

Comment: This request must show me 3 documents the first print show me " 3 documents found"

Comment: You are returning inside loop! Thats why you only see one

Comment: Same problem when I return outside the loop statement

Answer (score 9):

try "_doc" instead of "doc"

```
res = es.search(index="92c603b3-8173-4d7a-9aca-f8c115ff5a18", doc_type="_doc", body = {
'size' : 100,
'query': {
    'match_all' : {}
}
})
```

Answer (score 4):

Elasticsearch by default retrieve only 10 documents. You could change this behaviour - [doc here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-from-size.html) . The best practice for pagination are [`search after query`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/search-request-search-after.html) and [`scroll query`](http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/helpers.html#scan). It depends from your needs. Please read this answer [Elastic search not giving data with big number for page size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49320599/elastic-search-not-giving-data-with-big-number-for-page-size/49321145#49321145)

To show all the results:

```
for doc in res['hits']['hits']:
    print doc['_id'], doc['_source']
```

Comment: I have only 3 documents to get from this index

Comment: The problem is with the return statement of my function so how can I return the result correctly ?

Comment: just return data, which is defined as data = [doc for doc in res['hits']['hits']]

Comment: I want to return this result "%s %s %s" % (doc['_id'], doc['_source']['0'], doc['_source']['5'])

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `elasticsearch_dsl` and its Search API which allows you to iterate over all your documents via the `scan` method.

```py
import elasticsearch
from elasticsearch_dsl import Search

client = elasticsearch.Elasticsearch()
search = Search(using=client, index="92c603b3-8173-4d7a-9aca-f8c115ff5a18")

for hit in search.scan():
    print(hit)
```

Comment: search.scan() can go through all docs but it is very slow. Is there a way to improve it?

Comment: Now I found the doc https://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search_dsl.html#pagination seems like that's the best it can do.

Comment: It is unfortunate that this is as fast as it goes. I would be much interested if there was a way to speed things up?

Answer (score 0):

you can find info from here https://discuss.elastic.co/t/get-all-documents-from-an-index/86977/5

```py
es = Elasticsearch(["http://x.x.x.x:9200/"])
doc = {"size": 10000, "query": {"match_all": {}}}

resObj = es.search(index="myIndex", doc_type="myType", body=doc, scroll="1m")

download_alldata = []
download_alldata.extend(resObj["hits"]["hits"])

total_data_size = resObj["hits"]["total"]["value"]

allbar = tqdm(total=total_data_size, desc="processing")

download_data = []
download_data.extend(resObj["hits"]["hits"])
allbar.update(len(resObj["hits"]["hits"]))

while True:
    try:
        i = es.scroll(scroll_id=resObj["_scroll_id"], scroll="1m")["hits"][
            "hits"
        ]

        download_data.extend(i)
        # print(t)
        allbar.update(len(i))

        if len(i) == 0:
            break
    except Exception as e:
        break
    
    
print(len(download_data))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try the following query. It will return all the documents.

```
result = es.search(index="index_name", body={"query":{"match_all":{}}})
```

Comment: "search" function default return only 10 docs. You should at least increase the size.

Answer (score -1):

I dont see mentioned that the index must be refreshed if you just added data. Use this:

```
es.indices.refresh(index="index_name")
```