# Python API for Elastic Search - Getting 10000 in response every time

Tags: python, elasticsearch, kibana

```
client = Elasticsearch([host1, host2], http_auth=(user, password), scheme="http", port=port)
response = client.search(index="complats*", body={"from": 0, "size": 10000, "query": {
            "bool": {
                "must": [
                    {
                        "query_string": {
                            "query": "tags:\"prod\" AND severity:\"INFO\" AND service:\"abc-service\" AND msg:\"* is processed\"",
                            "fields": [],
                            "type": "best_fields",
                            "default_operator": "or",
                            "max_determinized_states": 10000,
                            "enable_position_increments": "true",
                            "fuzziness": "AUTO",
                            "fuzzy_prefix_length": 0,
                            "fuzzy_max_expansions": 50,
                            "phrase_slop": 0,
                            "escape": "false",
                            "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query": "true",
                            "fuzzy_transpositions": "true",
                            "boost": 1.0
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "range": {
                            "@timestamp": {
                                "from": "now-{}s".format((now.minute + 1) * 60),
                                "to": "now",
                                "include_lower": "true",
                                "include_upper": "true",
                                "boost": 1.0
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "adjust_pure_negative": "true",
                "boost": 1.0
            }
        }})
value = response['hits']['total']['value']
print(value)
```

The above query is successfully connecting to elasticsearch but returning an incorrect value or 10000 every time. What could be wrong here? I've read somewhere that elasticsearch module in python has a bug where it maxes out at 10000. Anyone else faced this problem? If yes how did u resolve it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Changing "max_determinized_states": 10000 isn't helping and it is still returning the same value.

Answer (score 2):

it isn't a python library bug, the impossibility to return more than 10000 results is a setting inherited from lucene. If you need more results you should use `search_after` query for pagination, or `scroll` query for a single heavy search, it depends from your use case. Have a look to my response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49320599/elastic-search-not-giving-data-with-big-number-for-page-size) to view an example of implementing these queries with python