Retrive all records from elasticsearch
I have an index on Elasticsearch that has more than 100K records.
The format of the index data is:
{
"_index": "isp_names",
"_id": "XX.XXX.XXX.X",
"_version": 1,
"_score": 1,
"_source": {
"XX.XXX.XXX.X": "Some Random ISP Name "
}
}

I am trying to get all records from Elasticsearch using Python. My goal is that when the server starts, all the records from Elasticsearch will be read and stored in a dict in memory cache (ip_address:isp_name).
I tried using the scroll API, but I am not sure how I can use it as per the ES guide (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/scroll-api.html)  it says they don't recommend using scroll API, the elasticsearch version I am using is 8.12.1.
Any pointers appreciated.

You can use elasticdump to retrieve all records from elasticsearch or opensearch to another elasticsearch or your local as JSON.
https://github.com/elasticsearch-dump/elasticsearch-dump

I can't use this one as app is based on python and I can't use libraries apart from elasticsearch library

If you want to directly use Elasticsearch cache, you can use eager_global_ordinals. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/eager-global-ordinals.html
Yes, Elasticsearch not recommends to use scroll_api any more for deep pagination it's recommended to use search_after. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/paginate-search-results.html#search-after

Kindly, check this one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49320599/elastic-search-not-giving-data-with-big-number-for-page-size
